# NodeJs, Mocha : Import from parent folder issue

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have the following structure thus:

Acceptance.Tests

```
Framework
|=> ApiPublsisher.js
Tests
|=> stackTests.js
```

In the Tests directory, I type 'npm run test' and get the following

```
Error: Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Acceptance.Tests\Framework\ApiPublsisher.js:1:12)
```

The module containing the test (stackTests.js) is referencing it:

```
const ApiPublsisher = require("../../Framework/ApiPublsisher.js");
```

The API Publiblisher file has:

```
var uuid = require("uuid/v4");    
class ApiPublsisher
{
    constructor(ApiBaseUrl)
    {
        this.apiBaseUrl= ApiBaseUrl;
    }

    sendWakeupRequest()
    {
        // Unimportant code here...
    }
}

module.exports = ApiPublsisher;
```

**If** I add UUID require to the tests module (stackTests.js) it works.